# imbedding Translation

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

In Munkres' book we have the imbedding theorem the term imbed I would like to ask those familiar with Portuguese what would be the best translation of these terms for these terms. I found immersed(imerso) and immersion(imersão) it is correct?

Thanks.

Comment: In spanish we use "inmersión" for imbedding and "inmerso" for imbedded. I'd imagine that, in portuguese, it would it would be similar.